# Azure IoT Edge のインストール途中でエラー

Tags: linux, azure

以下URLの手順に沿って Azure IoT Edge をインストールしようとしていますが、エラーが出て先に進めません。原因および回避策を教えて頂けないでしょうか？

[Debian ベースの Linux システムに Azure IoT Edge ランタイムをインストールする](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-edge-linux)

**構築環境**
Linux Debian9 (kernel 4.9)

**エラーメッセージ**

```
root@debian:/etc# apt-get install iotedge
パッケージリストを読み込んでいます... 完了
依存関係ツリーを作成しています
状態情報を読み取っています... 完了
インストールすることができないパッケージがありました。おそらく、あり得
ない状況を要求したか、(不安定版ディストリビューションを使用しているの
であれば) 必要なパッケージがまだ作成されていなかったり Incoming から移
動されていないことが考えられます。
以下の情報がこの問題を解決するために役立つかもしれません:

以下のパッケージには満たせない依存関係があります:
iotedge : 依存: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) しかし、インストールすることが
できません
E: 問題を解決することができません。壊れた変更禁止パッケージがあります。
```

Comment: 説明では Debian ベースとなっていますが、実際には **Ubuntu** や RasPi 向けの Debian (Raspbian) が対象のようなので、パッケージのバージョン依存の関係で Debian では簡単にはインストールできない気がします。

Answer (score 0):

OSに入っているlibsslの版数を1.1に上げてしまったのでは？
libssl1.0.2に入れ直すとかすれば良いのでしょう。
あるいは両方入っているなら、対応する方のインクルードとかライブラリを明示的に指定するとか。

[Debian 系であえて古い APT パッケージをインストールする方法](https://qiita.com/kitsuyui/items/d8940e093fa41b58fe71)

[Azure IoT Edge のサポートされるシステム](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/iot-edge/support)
[レベル2](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/iot-edge/support#tier-2)

> 次の表に示すシステムは、Azure IoT Edge と互換性があると見なされますが、Microsoft によってアクティブにテストまたは管理されてはいません。
>
> Debian 8
> Debian 9
> Debian 10
>
> Debian 10 システム (Raspian Buster を含む) は、IoT Edge がサポートしていないバージョンの OpenSSL を使用します。 IoT Edge をインストールする前に、次のコマンドを実行して以前のバージョンをインストールしてください。
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.2
> ```

Debian9:
libssl1.0.2 https://packages.debian.org/ja/stretch/libs/libssl1.0.2
libssl1.1   https://packages.debian.org/ja/stretch/libs/libssl1.1

libssl1.0-dev https://packages.debian.org/ja/stretch/libdevel/libssl1.0-dev
libssl-dev  https://packages.debian.org/ja/stretch/libssl-dev

[OpenSSL1.1.0と以前のバージョンとの互換性](https://http2.try-and-test.net/openssl1_1_0_tips.html)